# Getting the uploaded Source bundle from aws elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using AWS Beanstalk to deploy my java application ,and i created the zip file which i uploaded.
Now the question is can i download the source bundle that i uploaded to my pc again ? and where is the path where is stored ?

Thanks !

Comment: I was able to extract the data from app.jar file , so i was able to get the class files .

Answer (score 0):

Your application versions are stored on S3.

You can easily access them by heading to Beanstalk home page, then click on your application name (/!\ not the environment name) and click on 'Application versions' on the left menu.

From there you can see all the zip files you uploaded and where each one is deployed. Then you can either download, delete or deploy them by selecting one and using the 'Action' button at the top.